# Reactjs redux store state on page refresh. componentWillUnmount not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component like:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'


class MyView extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                Something
            </div>
        )
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("Hellooww world")
        actions.store_state() 
    }

}

export default MyView
```

Here when I refresh the page I want to call `actions.store_state()` funciton.

But when I refresh the page `componentWillUnmount()` is not called. How can I call any function or store the state to localStorage when page is refreshed.

Comment: Try it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: where should I call this ?? I mean in which lifecycle method ?

Comment: when component did mount `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => console.log('unload'));` i guess you can't do async operations in this handler. Don't forget to unsubscribe on `willUnmount`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Maxx answer:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'


class MyView extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                Something
            </div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', this.saveStore)
    }

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.saveStore)
    }

    saveStore = (e) => {
        actions.store_state() 
    }

}

export default MyView
```

Comment: Here whatever inside saveStore is calling as usual on componentDidMount .. I want something to be called when I refresh the page.. That function should be called and then page should be refreshed when I refresh the page

Comment: `saveStore` is not being called on `componentDidMount`... it is called when the event `onbeforeunload` is triggered, which is your best bet to try execute code before a page refresh...